# How to set label text in one scene from a different view controller

Tags: xcode

I am reading the Sam's Xcode in 24 hours and am practising segues. I have started one segue using the following code:
But I am finding that the text in my label in my destination view is not being set. Yet I have created an outlet for it in my `NewSceneViewController`.

```
 - (IBAction)startSegue:(id)sender {  
     [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toNewScene" sender:sender];     
    }  

 - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {  
    ViewController *startingViewController;  
    NewSceneViewController *myDestinationViewController;  

    startingViewController=(ViewController *)segue.sourceViewController;  

    myDestinationViewController=(NewSceneViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;  
    myDestinationViewController.myLabel.text=@"HI";
    }
```

Comment: If you are using storyboard, then try setting label-text from Attributes Inspector of Utilities Area.

Comment: I can set the label text. I am trying set it from a view controller - the view that initiates the segue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so im scrapping my previous answer...i was playing around and found that you can actually set a uilabels text...get this...after! you present a modal view controller.

```
ModalViewController *modalVC = [ModalViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ModalViewController" bundle:nil];

modalVC.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;

[self presentModalViewController:modalVC animated:YES];

modalVC.someLabel.text = @"what ever text you want...";
```

go figure. this can probably be done with storyboards as well but would need to manually override the 
`prepareForSegue:` & `performSegueWithIdentifier:` methods.

Comment: Thank you very much for that. You have put my mind at rest! I can now continue with the tutorials. I thought I was missing something. Having said that, I notice I can set the background colour in the view I am instantiating. I thought I might also be able to set the label text.

Comment: my guess is because the "view" gets instantiated first, and labels don't get allocated until "viewWillAppear:" or "viewDidLoad:". i think this can be proven by trying to set the label text in the "initWithNibName:" with what ever value. even though it't being statically set in that vc .m file, it will still be what ever you had it set to in interface builder.